# Homography Matrix for Image Stitching in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, homography

ive been trying to compute the homography matrix in matlab by using manually selected corresponding points from 2 images. here is my code so far:

```
    spoints = [330.756756756757,923.310810810811; %points from source image
    335.945945945946,1016.71621621622;
    495.081081081081,771.094594594595;
    498.540540540540,933.689189189189];
    dpoints = [310.000000000000,477.040540540540; %points from destination image
    320.378378378378,558.337837837838;
    462.216216216216,319.635135135135;
    469.135135135135,471.851351351351];
    %/////////////homography matrix///////////////////
    n = size(spoints, 1); 
    A = zeros(n*2,8); 
    b = zeros(n*2,1); 
    j=1;
    for i=1:n
        A(j,:)=[dpoints(i,1) dpoints(i,2) 1 0 0 0 -spoints(i,1)*dpoints(i,1) - spoints(i,1)*dpoints(i,2)];
        b(j,1)=spoints(i,1);
        j=j+1;
        A(j,:)=[0 0 0 dpoints(i,1) dpoints(i,2) 1 -spoints(i,2)*dpoints(i,1) -spoints(i,2)*dpoints(i,2)];
        b(j,1)=spoints(i,2);
        j=j+1;
    end

    x = (A\b);
    H = [x(1,1) x(2,1) x(3,1);
        x(4,1) x(5,1) x(6,1);
        x(7,1) x(8,1) 1];
```

this does not give the right H matrix. i checked via

```
    bla = zeros(4,3);
    bla(1,:,:)=H*[dpoints(1,:),1]';
    bla(2,:,:)=H*[dpoints(2,:),1]';
    bla(3,:,:)=H*[dpoints(3,:),1]';
    bla(4,:,:)=H*[dpoints(4,:),1]';
```

the bla matrix should be equal to spoints matrix but its not. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that in the first step.
There are algorithms like [DLT](http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/dlt/dlt.html) (Direct Linear Transform) in 2D and 3D, that are doing this consistently, most of which use SVD Singular Value Decomposition technique. SVD is implemented in MATLAB you can read about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html). You can use SVD instead of A\b.

Answer (score 0):

solved it. just had to switch the spoints with the dpoints and its done.